# Launch Android Service without AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, service

for my app I have written a class "AutoService", which extends from Service and is launched every hour by the AlarmManager.

Now I would like to launch this Service manually, without interrupting the one hour intervall and by pressing an actionbar button.
The Service is running in the background (naturally) and should not be visible at any time.

How would i achieve that?

I do not think, that example code is needed here, if so, just ask!

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Use `context.startService(Intent)`?

Comment: read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html). Vogella describes services very good